# Is it possible to execute query independently on each partition using colocated computing in IgniteCallable without explicitly joining on keys?

Tags: ignite

I have one client code which does get all the keys and then call the affinityCall which execute on server-node

Code on client side for computing on each partition

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> partitionMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Integer affKey : affKeys) {
    Integer partitionId = affinityFunction.partition(affKey);
    partitionMap.computeIfAbsent(partitionId, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(affKey);
}
Collection<IgniteFuture<Map<Integer, Double>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<String> cacheList = new ArrayList<>();
cacheList.add(CACHE_NAME);
for (int partitionId : partitionMap.keySet()) {
    IgniteFuture<Map<Integer, Double>> future = compute.affinityCallAsync(cacheList, partitionId, 
                                   new Worker(CACHE_NAME, partitionMap.get(partitionId)));
    futures.add(future);
}
```

Code for the worker is

```
public class Worker implements IgniteCallable<Map<Integer, Double>> {
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    private String cacheName;
    private List<Integer> keys;
    
    public Worker(String cacheName, List<Integer> keys){
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
        this.keys = keys;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<Integer, Double> call() throws Exception {
        IgniteCache<Object, Object> cache = ignite.cache(cacheName);
        SqlFieldsQuery query = 
           new SqlFieldsQuery("select affKey, sum(count) from Summary s
                             join table(affKey integer = ?) a 
                             on a.affKey = s.affKey 
                             join table(studyId integer = ?) st
                             on st.studyId = s.studyId
                             group by affKey")
           .setArgs((Object) keys.toArray());
        Map<Integer, Double> result = new HashMap<>();
        try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(query)) {
            for (List<?> record : cursor) {
                Integer affKey = (Integer) record.get(0);
                Double sum = (Double) record.get(1);
                result.put(affKey, sum);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In above case I'm joining on all the keys present in the partition. can anybody help how can we get rid of the extra join here.

More specifically this is query on which I'm working on.

```
public SqlFieldsQuery getQueryStringForGroup1() {
                String queryString = "select g.geneId as geneId, sum(count) as count, " +
                                "sum(g.rawMean) as sumRawMean, " +
                                "sum(g.squareRawMean) as sumSquareRawMean, " +
                                "sum(g.rawSess) as rawSess, " +
                                "sum(g.mean) as sumMean, " +
                                "sum(g.squareMean) as sumSquareMean, " +
                                "sum(g.squareSd) as sEss, " +
                                "sum(g.greaterThan0) as sumGreaterThan0 " +
                                "from GeneSummary g " +
                        
                                "join table(geneId integer = ?1) gn on g.geneId = gn.geneId " +
                                (filter.getStudyId().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(studyId integer = ?4) s on g.studyId = s.studyId ")
                                +
                                (filter.getCellType().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(cellType integer = ?7) ct on g.cellType = ct.cellType ")
                                +
                                (filter.getTissueType().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(tissueType integer = ?6) t on g.tissueType = t.tissueType ")
                                +
                                (filter.getCondition().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(condition integer = ?5) cd on g.condition = cd.condition ")
                                +
                                (filter.getAge().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(age integer = ?3) a on g.age = a.age ")
                                +
                                (filter.getGender().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(gender integer = ?2) gd on g.gender = gd.gender ")
                                +
                                "group by g.geneId";
                SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery(queryString).setArgs(
                                (Object) geneMap.keySet().toArray(),
                                (Object) filter.getGender().toArray(),
                                (Object) filter.getAge().toArray(),
                                (Object) filter.getStudyId().toArray(),
                                (Object) filter.getCondition().toArray(),
                                (Object) filter.getTissueType().toArray(),
                                (Object) filter.getCellType().toArray());
                                //.setPartitions(this.partitionId);
                // query.setPartitions(this.partitionId);
                return query;
        }
```

As you mentioned in the comment I modified argument to set for the query.

Modified query looks like this.

```
public SqlFieldsQuery getQueryStringForGroup1() {
                String queryString = "select g.geneId as geneId, sum(count) as count, " +
                                "sum(g.rawMean) as sumRawMean, " +
                                "sum(g.squareRawMean) as sumSquareRawMean, " +
                                "sum(g.rawSess) as rawSess, " +
                                "sum(g.mean) as sumMean, " +
                                "sum(g.squareMean) as sumSquareMean, " +
                                "sum(g.squareSd) as sEss, " +
                                "sum(g.greaterThan0) as sumGreaterThan0 " +
                                "from GeneSummary g " +
                                // "join \"GeneName\".\"GENENAME\" gn on g.geneId = gn.geneId and gn.partitionId
                                // = ?1 " +
                                // "join table(geneId integer = ?1) gn on g.geneId = gn.geneId " +
                                (filter.getStudyId().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(studyId integer = ?4) s on g.studyId = s.studyId ")
                                +
                                (filter.getCellType().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(cellType integer = ?7) ct on g.cellType = ct.cellType ")
                                +
                                (filter.getTissueType().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(tissueType integer = ?6) t on g.tissueType = t.tissueType ")
                                +
                                (filter.getCondition().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(condition integer = ?5) cd on g.condition = cd.condition ")
                                +
                                (filter.getAge().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(age integer = ?3) a on g.age = a.age ")
                                +
                                (filter.getGender().isEmpty() ? ""
                                                : "join table(gender integer = ?2) gd on g.gender = gd.gender ")
                                +
                                "group by g.geneId";
                SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery(queryString);
                if (!filter.getCellType().isEmpty())
                        query.setArgs(
                                        (Object) geneMap.keySet().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getGender().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getAge().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getStudyId().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getCondition().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getTissueType().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getCellType().toArray());
                if (!filter.getTissueType().isEmpty())
                        query.setArgs(
                                        (Object) geneMap.keySet().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getGender().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getAge().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getStudyId().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getCondition().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getTissueType().toArray());
                if (!filter.getCondition().isEmpty())
                        query.setArgs(
                                        (Object) geneMap.keySet().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getGender().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getAge().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getStudyId().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getCondition().toArray());
                if (!filter.getStudyId().isEmpty())
                        query.setArgs(
                                        (Object) geneMap.keySet().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getGender().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getAge().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getStudyId().toArray());
                if (!filter.getAge().isEmpty())
                        query.setArgs(
                                        (Object) geneMap.keySet().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getGender().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getAge().toArray());
                if (!filter.getGender().isEmpty())
                        query.setArgs(
                                        (Object) geneMap.keySet().toArray(),
                                        (Object) filter.getGender().toArray());

                query.setPartitions(this.partitionId);
                return query;
        }
```

Workaround to it was set atleast last argument in the query.

Now my question here is, which approach is better here ?
With join on affinity key or querying on each partition.

Comment: This might help: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/SqlFieldsQuery.html#setPartitions-int...-

Read through this: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/SQL/distributed-joins

Comment: @AlexK Thanks for your quick response. I tried with distributed join. It performs worse with the size of data we have compared to above code. Just wants to know if there is any way to execute sql field query on single partition without joining on affinity key.

Comment: Note : There is group by clause also on affinity key

Answer (score 0):

With the caveat that I've not studied your query, you can limit a query to a specific partition like this:

```
var q = new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from table")
        .setPartitions(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Stenphen. Getting following error when I tried to set the partition. Do partition go well with setArgs. 
'''
javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=e919da34-74d7-4d01-aa36-0d69c8678abe, errMsg=Failed to bind parameter [idx=1, obj=0, stmt=prep3293
'''

Comment: One more thing to note. I'm executing this on remove node with IgniteCallable. Do I need to call this from client?

Comment: It works when I try it. It looks like either you’re not setting the arguments or the arguments are the wrong type.

Comment: Thanks @stephen. It worked by setting the last argument of among all. I modified the query and edited the question .. Querying on each partition is better or joining on affinity keys?